# Why I can't download the file on a specific grid with an URL OpendDap on R studio?

Tags: r, opendap

:D

I'm trying to download many files with OpenDap in R software but I have a problem ...
Indeed, I want to download all files of GHRSST Level 4 MUR Global Foundation Sea Surface Temperature Analysis (v4.1)from 2002 to 2018 because I need to get the sea ice fraction.

But I just need these data on a specific grid so I would like to create a loop to download all files with some constraints of variables and latitude / longitude .
In the order to do this, I have got the URL for (an example) the 2019 september 20th :
https://podaac-opendap.jpl.nasa.gov:443/opendap/allData/ghrsst/data/GDS2/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/v4.1/2017/263/20170920090000-JPL-L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc?time[0:1:0],lat[2000:1:4000],lon[18000:1:27000],sea_ice_fraction[0:1:0][2000:1:4000][18000:1:27000]

When I try download this URL directly by the R software (function download.file), I have the whole of this file, all variables on the whole of the Earth so it's a great problem because each file make 330 Mo ... and the file that I want make less 100 Mo ...

My function in R studio is :
download.file("https://podaac-opendap.jpl.nasa.gov:443/opendap/allData/ghrsst/data/GDS2/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/v4.1/2017/263/20170920090000-JPL-L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc?time[0:1:0],lat[2000:1:4000],lon[18000:1:27000],sea_ice_fraction[0:1:0][2000:1:4000][18000:1:27000]",
"nc_20110910090000.nc.nc4",mode="wb")
I hope you can assist me ...

Kind regards,

Alexandre Modi

Comment: Sorry but a part of my message has left! 

It's "Hello everyone" at the beginning of this message.

Comment: then edit your message... :)

Comment: Oh, sorry ... I don't know how this forum works ! The next time, I'll edit my message. 
Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can only download files that exist. Does a file which contains exactly what you want actually exist? If not, your question is about extracting data from a file that you know how to download, in which case even talking about downloading is irrelevant. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, initially, I have a file which include the data on the whole of the Earth.
But with the OpenDAP in podaac, I can to subset the entire grid in a specific grid (to me is : between -70 / - 50 south and 0 and 90 east). This step is feasible by selecting variables and values that you desired on this adresse web : https://podaac-opendap.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/allData/ghrsst/data/GDS2/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/v4.1/2017/020/20170120090000-JPL-L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc.html
When we adjust variables and values, the constraints is added between hooks on the data URL.

Comment: So, when I put this previous adress and the constraints, I get "https://podaac-opendap.jpl.nasa.gov:443/opendap/allData/ghrsst/data/GDS2/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/v4.1/2017/263/20170920090000-JPL-L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc?time[0:1:0],lat[2000:1:4000],lon[18000:1:27000],sea_ice_fraction[0:1:0][2000:1:4000][18000:1:27000]. If I download the file with this adress on r studio, I get a file which include all the data and not only on my specific grid so the contraints are not taken into account ...
Is it necessary to add an argument in r function? 
Thank's a lot for your answer

Comment: I don't know why R seems to be using just part of the url. Perhaps this will help: https://lukemiller.org/index.php/2011/02/accessing-noaa-tide-data-with-r/

Comment: Thank you M. Coleman, I will se this web site. I hope that the solution will be here.